# How to find origin of permission in merged manifest?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-permissions

I added some libraries to an Android app and after upload to the Google Play Store I got this warning:

[image]

The main manifest file does not declare this permission, so I assume it comes from a library.
I then check out the source code of the previous version, which did not use this permission.

Looking at the merged manifest file in Android Studio, I still see the permission:
[image]

When I click on "Go to declaration" for this permission, it takes me to the main manifest file, which does not declare this permission.

I tried to clean and rebuild the project and restart Android Studio but the permission still shows in the merged manifest tab in Android Studio. It shows in the `debug` and `release` build variant.

Why is that?

Comment: There should be a manifest merger report under `app/build/outputs/logs`.

Comment: @Michael Good hint! The permission does not appear in the report, but it does in the "merged manifest" tab in Android Studio, so that tab seems to be broken. The issue was the latest FB SDK: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/665 If you add an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After building your app you should be able to find a manifest merger report under `app/build/outputs/logs`. Among other things, this file lists the origin of every permission that has been added to the merged manifest.

Comment: Thank you, sir! So many years of Android under my belt, and only TIL about this.